# Properties of sum set $A+A$ or $A+A+A$ of nonnegative integers

Tags: number-theory

I am wondering if there is any study on the sum of two or more sets, specifically when the sets are identical with nonnegative integer elements. The sum of two sets is defined as
\begin{equation*}
A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}
\end{equation*}
and the sum of three or more sets can be defined in a similar fashion. Some questions may be like: for $A+A+A$, what is the minimum ratio of $|A+A+A|/|A|$? If it contains all integers from $1$ to $3\max\{a\in A\}$, what is the minimal size of $A$? And general results to $nA$?

Comment: This is a hugely popular area in additive combinatorics eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős_sumset_conjecture

Comment: Thanks Funktorality! I found some references for that!